# ASP.NET5 MVC6 Deploy on Azure -- This web app has been successfully created

Tags: asp.net, azure, azure-web-app-service, asp.net-core-mvc

I am using linux to develop an MVC6-based website.  I would like to deploy it to azure, but have not been successful in deploying it.  I have done this successfully with a test project using the following steps:

1. use `yo aspnet` to create an MVC project
2. use `azure site create --git [name]` to create a site on azure, which configures an *azure* remote for the current git directory.
3. use `git push azure master` to push the default MVC6 project up.

This results in a successfully-deployed site [here](http://abcdefghij.azurewebsites.net).

When I try to follow the same process for the other site, though, the default azure page is shown [here](http://plaintexttransmissions.azurewebsites.net).

Since I am developing on linux, I had initially removed dnxcore and iis-related stuff from the modified `project.json`, but after considering that azure websites are probably running on IIS and windows machines rather than linux boxes, I added these options back into the `project.json`, with the result that the two `project.json`'s, from the test project and my project, were the same, in terms of dependencies and commands.

How could I figure out what is incorrectly configured for my second site that is preventing it from successfully deploying?  The `project.json` of my second site is as follows:

```
{
  "webroot": "wwwroot",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "dependencies": {
    "CommonMark.NET": "0.9.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics": "1.0.0-beta5",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-beta5",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.TagHelpers": "6.0.0-beta5",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.IIS": "1.0.0-beta5",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0-beta5",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener": "1.0.0-beta5",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-beta5",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Tooling.Razor": "1.0.0-beta5",
    "Microsoft.Framework.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0-beta5",
    "Microsoft.Framework.Logging": "1.0.0-beta5",
    "Microsoft.Framework.Logging.Console": "1.0.0-beta5",
    "Kestrel": "1.0.0-beta5"
  },
  "commands": {
    "kestrel": "Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting --server Kestrel --config hosting.ini",
    "web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting --server Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener --config hosting.ini"
  },
  "frameworks": {
    "dnx451": {},
    "dnxcore50": {}
  },
  "exclude": [
    "wwwroot",
    "node_modules",
    "bower_components"
  ],
  "publishExclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "bower_components",
    "**.xproj",
    "**.user",
    "**.vspscc"
  ],
  "scripts": {
    "prepublish": [
      "npm install",
      "bower install",
      "gulp clean",
      "gulp min"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm having this same issue. I'm using VS 2015 and the built-in publish functionality. Did you find any solution yet?

Answer (score 1):

Considering you say that the two `project.json` files are the same, it is indeed strange that one website works while the other doesn’t.

In addition, it is difficult to see if the issue is related to code or to Azure.

Did you try switching `website1` and `website2`?

For example:
`Website1` is currently deployed on the http://abcdefghij.azurewebsites.net/ and it works.
`Website2` is currently deployed on http://plaintexttransmissions.azurewebsites.net/ and nothing is showing.

Try deploying `website1` on http://plaintexttransmissions.azurewebsites.net/ and `website2` on http://abcdefghij.azurewebsites.net/ and see if this works.

You’ll be able to see if the error is related to something in your code of if it is related to Azure.

Comment: Great suggestion, thank you.  It appears to be something with my code, the next step would be to figure out what!  I usually run my site with _dnx kestrel_ command in linux, navigate to localhost:5000 and am presented with my homepage.  Perhaps it could be something with the routing?